# Linear time-invariant system

Tags: signal, system

Hey all I have the following question and I am having trouble getting to the correct answer. Here is what I have: (sorry I do not understand how to format the question)

Consider a linear time-invariant system such that

$$H(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{2}e^{j\omega})^2}$$

If the input x ̃[n] is periodic with period N<sub>0</sub> = 8, then determine the output Fourier series coefficient y<sub>4</sub> if x<sub>4</sub> = 9.

I have this so far:

$$y_4 = x_4 H(e^{jk\frac{2\pi}{N_0}})$$

$$= 9 H(e^{j\pi})$$

Goes back into the given function:

$$= \frac{9}{(1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-j\omega})^2}$$

I am stuck here. How would I get a solid answer from this. I know that in the end the answer is 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't really able to follow your reasoning, but I can tell you how you can simplify your second equation:

$$9 H(e^{j\pi})$$

Note that $$e^{j\pi} = -1$$
([Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)).

Inserting that into the equation above gives:

$$ \frac{9}{(1-\frac{1}{2}(-1))^2} = \frac{9}{1.5^2}= 4$$
I hope this helps ;)

Comment: I've cancelled my downvote - It's probably best to remove all the comments now. If you make a trivial edit like I did it removes me from the "edited by" section!

Comment: So is that always equal to -1? I have never heard of that but it does make sense.

Comment: *e* is a constant, *j* is a constant, pi is a constant, so yes, $$e^{-j\pi}$$ is also a constant which is always equal to -1. Euler's fomula, which I linked to above, is really *the* most basic equation for everything related to complex numbers.